# Posting list of objects to webApi controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have the following code:

```
var keys = [];
keys.push({"classKey":"Dashboard","resourceKey":"Today's turnover"});
keys.push({"classKey":"Dashboard","resourceKey":"Get an overview directly from your receipts on location."});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Api/TranslationsApi/GetTranslationsByClassKey",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ translations: keys }),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.Data);
    }
});
```

And this WebAPI controller:

```
  public class TranslationsApiController : ApiController
  {
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetTranslationsByClassKey([FromBody]List<TranslationRequestModel> translations)
    {
      return new JsonResult { Data = translations.Count };
    }
  }
```

TranslationRequestModel:

```
  public class TranslationRequestModel
  {
    public string ClassKey { get; set; }
    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }
  }
```

The request payload looks like this:

[image]

However, I get a

> translate.js:40 POST
>   http://localhost/Api/TranslationsApi/GetTranslationsByClassKey 404
>   (Not Found)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In WebApi(**Rest**) calls you don't call the method like you had to do with Old WebServices. You only use the Controller name without the word Controller like:

```
/Api/TranslationsApi
```

In Rest in order to have multiple POST or GET methods you need a unique URL for each like:

```
  /Api/TranslationsApi/{param1}/{param2}
```

In WebApi2 you could do this using `RouteAttribute` like:

```
 [Route("api/TranslationsApi/{param1}"), HttpPost]
 public string PostMe2(int param1)
   return "another POST value";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post to `/Api/TranslationsApi/` if you setup your routes with the default route template:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You should also post just the array if you want your controller action to bind to the list. So the js should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Api/TranslationsApi/",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(keys),
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.Data);
    }
});
```